# I can't figure out what is wrong with my Tkinter Mortgage Calculator? Any advice would be great

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having a problem with this code. To calculate mortgage how much you pay for your mortgage monthly, despite this everyone I have spoken to, can't determine what the problem is. So I have come here to see if any of you are able to help? Thanks a lot :)

```
from tkinter import * #Imports the tkinter library
mortgage=Tk() #Names the interface as 'mortgage'
mortgage.geometry("800x500+200+200")  #Defines the dimensions of the interface
mortgage.title("Mortgage")

#calculation method
def Calculate():
    loantotal1=float(loantotal.get())
    interestrate1=float(interestrate.get())
    loanperiod1=float(loanperiod.get())

    interestCalculation =float( interestrate1 / 100)
    totalcost = float(loantotal1 * interestCalculation)
    numberofmonths=float(loanperiod1 / 12)
    monthlycost= float(totalcost / loanperiod1)
    monthly_period.set=("Your monthly payment %2.f "%monthlycost)

#variables
loantotal=StringVar()
interestrate=StringVar()
loanperiod=StringVar()
monthly_period=StringVar()

#interface
welcome_message=Label(mortgage,text="Find out how much you'll pay monthly    for your mortgage,",font="Arial 12 bold",fg="#000000").pack()
instruction_message=Label(mortgage,text="Enter your details below and then          Click submit:",font="Arial 12 bold",fg="#000000").pack()

loanTotal=Label(mortgage,text="Loan Total:",font="Arial 11     bold",fg="#000000").place(x=280,y=63)
loanTotal=Label(mortgage,text="£",font="Arial 11 bold",fg="#000000").place(x=550,y=63)
loanTotal_textbox=Entry(mortgage,textvariable=loantotal).place(x=400,y=65)

interestRate=Label(mortgage,text="Interest Rate:",font="Arial 11 bold",fg="#000000").place(x=280,y=88)
interestRate=Label(mortgage,text="%",font="Arial 11 bold",fg="#000000").place(x=550,y=88)
interestRate_textbox=Entry(mortgage,textvariable=interestrate).place(x=400,y=90)

loanPeriod=Label(mortgage,text="Loan Period:",font="Arial 11 bold",fg="#000000").place(x=280,y=113)
loanPeriod=Label(mortgage,text="Years",font="Arial 11 bold",fg="#000000").place(x=550,y=113)
loanPeriod_textbox=Entry(mortgage,textvariable=loanperiod).place(x=400,y=115)

Label(mortgage,textvariable=monthly_period).place(x=400,y=135)



submit_button=Button(mortgage,text="Calculate",command=Calculate,font="Arial 11 bold",fg="#000000").place(x=280,y=170)

mortgage.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific: What do you expect? What happens?

Answer (score 1):

```
monthly_period.set=("Your monthly payment %2.f "%monthlycost)
```

You should be calling the `set` method, not assigning to it... remove that equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

Add at the beginning of the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Also, if you are using Python2, write the Tk import like this:

```
from Tkinter import * #Imports the tkinter library
```

Comment: PEP8 discourages wildcard imports.

Comment: @BryanOakley You are totally right, but I am just modifying his code. Not only PEP8, it is a good behavior to avoid wildcard imports in every programming language.